# Find the string length of a Lua number?

Tags: lua

Easy question here, probably, but searching did not find a similar question.

The # operator finds the length of a string, among other things, great.  But with Lua being dynamically typed, thus no conversion operators, how does one type a number as a string in order to determine its length?

For example suppose I want to print the factorials from 1 to 9 in a formatted table.

```
i,F = 1,1
while i<10 do
    print(i.."! == "..string.rep("0",10-#F)..F)
    i=i+1
    F=F*i
end
```

error:  attempt to get length of global 'F' (a number value)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

why not use `tostring(F)` to convert `F` to a string?

Comment: While this does work, HennyH has the correct answer.  There is no reason to do tuns of string operations when there's a fast formula

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively,

```
length = math.floor(math.log10(number)+1)
```

Careful though, this will only work where n > 0!

Comment: `log10` is deprecated as of LUA 5.2, `log` should work fine

Answer (score 5):

There are probably a dozen ways to do this. The easy way is to use `tostring` as Dan mentions. You could also concatenate an empty string, e.g. `F_str=""..F` to get `F_str` as a string representation. But since you are trying to output a formatted string, use the `string.format` method to do all the hard work for you:

```
i,F = 1,1
while i<10 do
    print(string.format("%01d! == %010d", i, F))
    i=i+1
    F=F*i
end
```

Comment: The important part of the question was to determine the string length of a number, which Dan answered, but thanks anyway for solving the example another way.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `while tostring(F).len < 10 do` useful?